# How to change url of remote in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to change my url in remote function of jquery validate every I click on button 1 or button 2  but not reload page

```
    $("#serviceform").validate({
       ignore: "",
       rules:{
            servicename:{
              required: true,
              minlength: 3,
              remote:{
                url: ($('#serviceid').val() == "newid88765789") ? url2:url1,// alert(1):alert(2), 
                type:"POST"
                },
            },
       }  
     });
```

Comment: You should edit your OP to show us the relevant HTML of the form including the buttons, and also explain the purpose of doing this.

Comment: On one hand, you said you want the URL to depend on which button is clicked, then on the other hand, you're showing us a conditional where the URL depends on the value of `serviceid`.  Which is it?

Answer (score -1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, nor can we see your HTML.  On one hand, you said you want the URL to depend on which button is clicked, then on the other hand, you're showing us a conditional where the URL depends on the value of `serviceid`.  These are two different things.

If your conditional is correct, simply enclosing the `url` parameter within a JavaScript function should work...

```
$("#serviceform").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules:{
        servicename:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            remote: {
                url: function() {
                    return ($('#serviceid').val() == "newid88765789") ? url2 : url1;
                }, 
                type:"POST"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

Otherwise, the only way to change a parameter of a particular rule upon the click of a certain button is to use [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) within a `click` handler.  Do not forget to programmatically trigger a validation test of the form after the rule is changed.

```
$('#button_one').on('click', function(e) {

    // block default submit
    // would not need this for 'type="button"'
    e.preventDefault;

    // add/change the remote rule
    $('input[name="servicename"]').rules('add', {
        remote: {
            url:  // your url for button 1,
            type: "POST"
        }
    });

    // trigger a validation test of the entire form
    $("#serviceform").valid();

});

$('#button_two').on('click', function(e) {

    // block default submit
    // would not need this for 'type="button"'
    e.preventDefault;

    // add/change the remote rule
    $('input[name="servicename"]').rules('add', {
        remote: {
            url:  // your url for button 2,
            type: "POST"
        }
    });

    // trigger a validation test of the entire form
    $("#serviceform").valid();

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to click on the button 1, jquery validate will check if servicename value already exists in the database. When I click on button 2, it will check if servicename value is a valid value.
Thanks for your help, I have found the solution by disabling validator and reactivate it

var form = $('#serviceform').get(0);
        $.removeData(form,'validator');